The Nature of Free Will
How does the concept of free will reconcile with the deterministic view of the universe, and what implications does this have for moral responsibility and personal agency?

This is a massive question addressed by lengthy entries on sites such as the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. You're much better off reading those first, then asking narrower questions here, perhaps about anything those sites leave unaddressed.

Related: What are the implications of accepting that we don't have free will?

Also this question is duplicate with many others on this site.

The Classical Philosophy tries to speak in absolute terms. This creates a logical utopia because there is nothing absolute in this reality.
But according to Simulation Theory, the mixture of different influences supporting our reality includes some fraction of both; free will and determinism.
